# Does grails domain delete() update amount of a children within a transaction

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'll be answering this myself by testing, but thought I would race stackoverflow community...

In a grails domain transaction, does the number of child records change inside of the transaction (for example with delete)

```
MyDomain.withTransaction{status->
    try{
       while(parent.children.size()>4){
          parent.children[0].delete(flush:true);
      }
    }
    catch(org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException e){
        status.setRollbackOnly();
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. Though grails would not allow access to the children by children[0]. I had to get around this by using children.collect{it}[0] or
children.iterator().next()

Test:

```
 def p=new TestParentDomain();
 def i=0
 while(i<3){
     def child=new TestChildDomain();
     m.addToChildren(child);
    i++
 }
 m.save(flush:true);
 println p.children.size() //3   

 TestParentDomain.withTransaction{status->
    while(m.children.size()>1){
       m.removeFromChildren(m.children.iterator).next()).save(flush:true)
    }
 }
 println m.children.size();//1
```